# How to convert a variable to a JSON using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

I've tried to convert a variable into a JSON string but the output is not appropriate on what I wanted.

I've already tried the code below but the output is not in JSON format.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\somedirectory\\Payout.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FundTransferMap>();
                var list = csv.GetRecords<FundTransfer>().ToList().Dump();
                var viewModel = new FundTransfer();
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = serializer.Serialize(list);
                Response.Write(json);
                return View();
            }
```

The output of this code on the `Response.Write` is this

```
[Count: 1]
-- MVC.Models.FundTransfer State -- 
    senderRefId: TRANSFER-0001
    tranRequestDate: 2018-08-10T08:40:45.897
    particulars: particulars
    sender: 
        [Count: 1]
        -- MVC.Models.Sender State -- 
            name: Name1
            address: 
                [Count: 1]
                -- MVC.Models.Address State -- 
                    line1: line1
                    line2: line2
                    city: city
                    province: province
                    zipcode: zipcode
                    country: Country
```

But I wanted it to be like this

```
{
    "senderRefId": "TRANSFER-0001",
    "tranRequestDate":"2018-08-10T08:40:45.897",
    "particulars":"particulars",
    "sender": {
      "name":"Name1",
      "address": {
            "line1":"Line1",
            "line2":"Line2",
            "city":"city",
            "province":"province",
            "zipCode":"zipcode",
            "country":"country"
          }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Set Response `ContentType`. `ContentType = "application/json";`

Comment: Have you try to debug it? What is in `json` variable right before `Response.Write(json);` call?

Comment: Yes, The data of the `json` variable is right before the json text shown above. The second group of codes. The one with the `[Count:1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Convert DataTable to JSON using JSON.Net DLL (Newtonsoft).

Now in this method, we will convert our C# Datatable to JSON using the Newtonsoft DLL.

For this first, you need to download JSON.Net DLL. You can download it from Nuget.org and then import the Newtonsoft.JSON namespace into our page as in the following code. JSON.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kwingkwing.ko. I've solve my problem using this code

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csv.GetRecords<FundTransfer>());
Response.Write(json);
```

This converted my object to a JSON.

Comment: Great! Happy Coding Brotha!